# How to authenticate with Windows login to SQL Server with pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I can successfully connect to database with SQL Management Studio with Authentication "Windows Authentication" or "Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA".

I have currently login with MFA to SQL Server Management Studio.

However Windows login with pyodbc fails. I wonder what is wrong.
I have tried to add 'UID=my.name@domain.com;' , but same error.

CODE:

```
import pyodbc 

conndev = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
              'Server=server124.database.windows.net,1433;Trusted_Connection=No;'
              'Database=db345;'
              'UID=username;'
              'PWD=password;')
```

ERROR:

```
conndev = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
pyodbc.Error: ('FA004', "[FA004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed 
to authenticate the user '' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 
'WindowsIntegrated').\r\nError code 0xCAA82EEF; state 10\r\nThe request to connect and log on 
to an server failed. (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [FA004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
Server] 
[SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user '' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 
'WindowsIntegrated').\r\nError code 0xCAA82EEF; state 10\r\nThe request to connect and log on 
to an server failed. (0)")
```

Comment: i am having the same problem ... is there any solution?